# python cross referencing two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reference

Say I have two arrays of similar dimensions. One is filled with numbers 1 to 6 and the other is filled with the letters a, b and c.

In the end I want to have an array where a, b and c are replaced with the maximum value the corresponding cells in the other array have:

```
x= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,]]
y= [[a,b,c],[b,c,a]]
```

I would like:

```
z = [[6,4,5],[4,5,6]]
```

I cant get my head around it, I feel like it should be possible with `np.where` and `max`, but I hope you guys can help me. cheers

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us some code that you have tried.

Comment: Is your `y` definitely only containing single letters?

Comment: @user3640696, did any of these solutions help? if so, please select one so others can see what's tried & tested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre-compute the max values for each letter and keep it for later. You can use a Dictionary for it:

```
dict = {}
for i in len(y):
  for j in len(y[i]):
    c = y[i][j]
    if not c in dict:
      dict[c] = x[i][j]
    else:
      dict[c] = max([dict[c], x[i][j]])
```

Finally just use the dict to generate `z` from `y`:

```
z = []
for a in len(y):
  arr = []
  for c in a:
    arr.append( dict[ c ] )
  z.append(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution, using `np.where` and `np.max` as you suggest. If performance is not a criterion, it may be difficult to perform the task with less code.

```
import numpy as np

x= np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6,]])
y= np.array([['a','b','c'],['b','c','a']])

coords = {i: list(zip(*np.where(np.array(y)==i))) for i in np.unique(y)}
max_map = {k: np.max([x[c] for c in v]) for k, v in coords.items()}

result = np.vectorize(max_map.get)(y)

# array([[6, 4, 5],
#        [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `y` contains only a handful of different letters you can indeed use `where`:

```
import numpy as np
import string

def f_where(x, y, letters):
    z = np.empty_like(x)
    for l in letters:
        w = np.where(y==l)
        z[w] = np.max(x[w])
    return z

n = 10
y = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters[:4]), size=(n,))
x = np.random.randint(0, n, size=(n,))

print(x)
print(y)
print(f_where(x, y, string.ascii_letters[:4]))
```

Sample output:

```
[3 6 5 9 5 6 8 1 8 2]
['d' 'a' 'c' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'c' 'a']
[3 9 8 9 6 6 8 3 8 9]
```

But when the number of letters is a bit larger (say `~50`), this method becomes rather slow. In this case the following method which uses `argpartition` performs much better:

```
def f_argpart(x, y):
    dtype = next(d for d in map(np.dtype, np.sctypes['int'])
                 if d.itemsize == y.dtype.itemsize)
    yv=y.view(dtype=dtype)

    counts = np.cumsum(np.bincount(yv)[ord('A'):])
    inds = np.argpartition(yv, counts[:-1])
    mx = np.empty((ord('A') + len(counts),), dtype=x.dtype)
    mx[ord('A'):] = np.maximum.reduceat(x[inds], np.r_[0, counts[:-1]])

    return mx[yv]

print(f_argpart(x, y))

n = 10000
y = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), size=(n,))
x = np.random.randint(0, n, size=(n,))

kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=1000)
from timeit import repeat

print(repeat('f_argpart(x, y)', **kwds))
print(repeat('f_where(x, y, string.ascii_letters)', **kwds))
```

Sample output:

```
[3 9 8 9 6 6 8 3 8 9]
[0.48244034708477557, 0.46697514806874096, 0.46860265801660717]
[4.792020458960906, 4.818586917826906, 4.785608761012554]
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for z=[[534],[345]??

Since the arrays start counting at 0?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? OP doesn't use indexing at all, so it shouldn't matter that the index count in Python starts at 0.